# css style for dropdownbox doesnt take effect on iphone

Tags: html, css, iphone

I have no problem styling the background color of textboxes, on PC it's ok but on iPhone the style for dropdown box doesn't take effect.

Css:

```
input[type=text],
input[type=submit],
select {
  background-color:#272822;
}
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried adding !important? only the background-color not working or the whole style?

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) in which you reproduce the problem?

Comment: (at)Felix what's the syntax for !important? haven't heard it though, I'm sorry, (at)barnee http://jsfiddle.net/yuuto/2tcQA/

Comment: Have you tried: `-webkit-appearance: none;` Removes default chrome and safari style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added `-webkit-appearance: none;` to your code.

<kbd>**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2tcQA/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: For that you'll find more information [here](http://signalvnoise.com/posts/2609-customizing-web-forms-with-css3-and-webkit).

Answer (score 0):

You could try using jquery form styling - this might work better cross platform. The one i often use is: http://uniformjs.com/